# Debugging a Managed Component from C++ Win32

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, winapi, com-interop

I have a Win32 EXE that's written in VC++. I have implementation written in C#. I've got the VC++ EXE consuming the C# DLL as outlined here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736. Works great, but I need to be able to debug. Both projects are loaded into the same .SLN, but breakpoints in the C# are never hit. Is there a way to debug this in VS2012?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ah, turns out this is easy if you know the right button to push. On the C++ project properties, Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Debugger Type = "Mixed".

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a Project reference to the C# Dll from the C++ Project.  If you have already done that,  Please clean up the solution and build. This should solve the problem.

Comment: I set a breakpoint just after the instantiation of C# component. Looking at the Modules window, I see the DLL is marked "The module did not load at the default load address" and "Skipped loading symbols for NGen binary." 

Clicking Symbol Load Info gives: "This module is a pre-compiled binary created by the ngen.exe tool. The debugger does not attempt to load symbols for these binaries, but will instead load symbols for original dll/exe when it is loaded by the .NET Runtime."

Clicking Load Symbols lets me browse to the .PDB (which it already seems to know about), but doesn't help.